# Custom new operation in Tensorflow results in exception 'pointer being freed was not allocated'

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning how to add operation to tensorflow following [Google's tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html), but run into some trouble.

I cloned the sources from the Github, and plan to add the `Fact` operation in `tensorflow/core/user_ops/fact.cc` to the framework. Following is my approach:

1. Create a `BUILD` file in `tensorflow/core/user_ops/`, with the content:

> ```
> load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")
>
> tf_custom_op_library(
>     name = "fact.so",
>     srcs = ["fact.cc"]
> )
> ```

2. Run following command in the root directory of the cloned project:

> bazel build -c opt -s //tensorflow/core/user_ops:fact.so

This does create a `fact.so` file in `bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/`

3. Copy the generated `fact.so` to my Python project, which is located is another irrelevant place.
4. In the Python project, run

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
>
> fact_module = tf.load_op_library('fact.so')
> with tf.Session(''):
>   print(fact_module.fact2().eval())
> ```

The result is an exception:

> python(77790,0x7fff742f7000) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x1c890ffde89: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Abort trap: 6

However, if I build the operation directly using clang++ like:

> clang++ -std=c++11 -shared tensorflow/core/user_ops/fact.cc -o
>   ~/Desktop/fact.so -fPIC -I $TF_INC -undefined dynamic_lookup

where $TF_INC is computed by

> TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf;
>   print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')

everything works fine.

Could anyone tell my why the first approach failed?

Comment: Could you please tell the version of gcc on your machine?